# resuming camera.preview() after photo has been taken

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a surfaceview which is displaying a camera preview I have it taking a picture and display it on the surfaceview but when I press the back button it closes the application but I want it to display the original camera preview.

I also only want to reset the display when the picture is being displayed and have normally functionality returned to back button when camera preview is showing.

```
public class cameraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
 private SurfaceView preview=null;
 private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
 private Camera camera=null;
 private ImageButton bt = null;
 private Toast t = null;
 private Camera.Parameters param = null; 
 private Button b = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.cam);

  t = Toast.makeText(this, "Just Click The Magnifying Glass To Search", 5000);//creates a new pop up message that lasts for 5 seconds

  t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER,   0, 0);
     t.show();




 b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test);
 b.setOnClickListener(search);
 bt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);//creates instance of button
 bt.setOnClickListener(search);//starts an on click listener for button



  preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.myview);//creates instance of surfaceview
  previewHolder=preview.getHolder();//creates a surfaceholder
  previewHolder.addCallback(this);//sets surfaceholder callback as the activity
  previewHolder.setType(3);//sets the type to SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS
```

}

```
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { //creates a method that is called automatically when the surface is changed
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();//sets param to be equal to camera parametors
        param.setPreviewSize(width, height);//sets width and height to that of what is passed back to it when callback calls it 
        //param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(param);//sets the camera parameters to param
        camera.startPreview();//starts the preview
        camera.autoFocus(cb);//calls autofocus callback method

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {//called when the surface has been created
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = Camera.open();//opens the camera and sets it to the camera variable




        try{
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);//sets the display area to previewHolder


        }catch(Throwable t){
            Log.e(""+t, null);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {//called when sureface is destroyed or when activity is closed
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();//stops the preview
        camera.release();//releases the camera
        camera = null;// clears the camera so it contains no information 
    }





    AutoFocusCallback cb = new AutoFocusCallback(){
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return true;
    }

    };




    private OnClickListener search = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // do something when the button is clicked
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.test:
                param = camera.getParameters();
            if(param.getFlashMode().equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)){
                /*
                 * IF statement to check the current flash mode and change it appropriately
                 */
                param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(param); 
            }else{
            param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(param);
            }

            break;

            case R.id.button:
                camera.autoFocus(cb);//calls autofocus with call back of cb
                  Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                         public void run() { 

                             camera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);

                         } 
                    }, 2000);           
                     break; 

                }

            }

    };





    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

            bt.setVisibility(4);
            b.setVisibility(4);
            b.setEnabled(false);
            bt.setEnabled(false);



        }
    };
```

above is my entire code (minus the imports) of my activity.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is override the onBackPressed() method:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed()
{    
  // Restart camera
}
```